# Getting current class

Tags: reflection, kotlin

how can I get the current class in Kotlin. For example if there are the abstract class "Animal" and the child-class "Dog" (witch is a child of "Animal") how can I get the class of "Dog" in "Animal". I don't now witch classes will use "Animal"

I already tried to use:

```
this::class
```

(what could be in Java):

```
this.getClass()
```

But this method is according to my IDE not available.

Best regards

Jonas Franz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `javaClass` to get a `Class` instance for `this` object. If you want to get a `Class` object for a particular class literal use `Dog::class.java`.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried this but my IDE said that "javaClass" is an unresolved reference but if I compile it it will works fine. I'm going to report this bug to JetBrains. Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aucyqadcu0j0xsc/Screenshot%202016-04-11%2019.17.37.png?dl=0